# How to dissolve geodatabase map across two subdivision levels in Arcgis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.2, dissolve

The existing polygon database contains attribute table with the following structure, and has three levels; country, state, and city (and many other countries not listed below).  I want to dissolve the map at country level, but for some specific countries. I want further dissolve them at state level.

Thanks.

```
ID_0    country ID_1    state   ID_2    city    ID_state    ID_city
48      China   01      Anhui   08      Hefei   4801        480108
48      China   01      Anhui   08      Hefei   4801        480108
48      China   01      Anhui   15      Tongling4801        480115
48      China   02      Jiangsu 14      Suzhou  4802        480214
48      China   03      Fujian  15      Fuzhou  4803        480315
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new attribute called "dissolve", and calculate it to be whatever unique value you wish to use for the dissolve.

Eg, "for some specific countries" you would calculate **dissolve** to be "Country + State", while for the other countries you would calculate **dissolve** to be simply "Country".

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Thanks for your quick answer.  By the way, how do you deal with <Null> in field calculation.

Comment: Glad it helped. What's the context of the <Null> - where is it causing a problem?

Comment: For the above example, if ID_1 in the first row is <Null>, the calculated ID_state will be <Null>.

Comment: You could use an IF statement to check whether the value is null - if so, use some other value to signify that there is no value